# Find the index of closest number in array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

Im using javascript for this.
I have an dataset as followings:

```
var filteredValues = [{
                        type1 : [ ],
                        type2 : [{w:86,h:108,l:66}, {w:86,h:109,l:66}],
                        type3 : [{w:82,h:110,l:73}]
                     }]
```

I want to be able to filter this dataset to the nearest item based on the values of `h` provided by the user.
Example: if the user provides `105` as `h`, the below would happen

- `type1` will be discarded as nothing is selected there at the moment.
- `105` would match against `h` value of `type2` and `type3` and whichever is closest, would be selected. In this case, `{w:86,h:108,l:66}` from `type2` as `105` is closest or equal to `109` or `110` (from `type3`) .
- the result of the output would be the type name, in this case `type2`

Please feel free to correct the question if you see any mistakes. Also if you think changing dataset can make it easier, let me know.

Below are few interesting thread that may be helpful

[How to find nearest element in nested array javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187794/how-to-find-nearest-element-in-nested-array-javascript)

[Find object in array with closest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57411383/find-object-in-array-with-closest-value)

Update:

I tried the following

```
function getResult(filteredValues, 105){
      filteredValues.reduce((acc, obj) =>
         Math.abs(y - obj.s) < Math.abs(y - acc.s) ? obj : acc
      );
}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: yes, very much. I wasnt able to do this myself

Comment: _"Find the **index**..."_ (which doesn't make much sense in an object) but then _"the result of the output would be the type **name**"_

Comment: @Andreas i will update the question with what i have done.

Comment: `filteredValues` is an array with _one_ element. Iterating over that one object doesn't make much sense. You have to iterate over the properties of that single object. Also `getResult()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: What is your expected output? Is it just `type2`? If so, I wonder how you'll be using this. If it's to retrieve the object with the closest value, then you would need its index in the `type2` array, and also the index of the object it belongs to from the `filteredValues` array.

Comment: I was able to make it work from Thomas's answer. Thank you so much. Very insightful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just written this code and it seems to work, but it would need to be tested more (it's bigger but maybe more understandable):

```js
const filteredValues = [
  {
    type1: [],
    type2: [
      { w: 86, h: 108, l: 66 },
      { w: 86, h: 109, l: 66 },
    ],
    type3: [{ w: 82, h: 106, l: 73 }],
  },
];

function filter(h) {
  const keys = Object.keys(filteredValues[0]);
  const values = Object.values(filteredValues[0]);
  const length = keys.length;
  let tempType = keys[0];
  let tempClosestHValue = values[0][0]?.h ?? Infinity;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    const type = values[i];
    const key = keys[i];
    if (type.length > 0) {
      let closestHValue = Math.abs(type[0].h - h);
      for (let y = 0; y < values[i].length; y++) {
        let data = values[i][y];
        if (Math.abs(data.h - h) < closestHValue) {
          closestHValue = data.h;
        }
      }
      if (closestHValue < tempClosestHValue) {
        tempClosestHValue = closestHValue;
        tempType = key;
      }
    }
  }
  return tempType;
}

console.log(filter(105));
```

which returns "type3", but if you modify the `h` property of the third type to 110, you get "type2" as the output.

Comment: This worked as expected. I will spend sometime understanding what is really happening. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ashish You're welcome. Basically I loop over all the values of your data, then the program calculates the difference between each `h` property in order to find the lowest difference (=minimum), and at the same time we save the name of the key that has the lowest h found until now. I hope it's clear :)

Answer (score 1):

This solution takes only the object of the given data.

With the entries,

- filter empty arrays
- map the result of reducing the array by taking the absolute delta to get the smallest possible value to the target value.

At the end create a new object from entries.

```js
const
    data = { type1: [], type2: [{ w: 86, h: 108, l: 66 }, { w: 86, h: 109, l: 66 }], type3: [{ w: 82, h: 110, l: 73 }] },
    height = 105,
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(data)
        .filter(([_, { length }]) => length)
        .map(([k, v]) => [k, v.reduce((a, b) => Math.abs(a.h - height) <= Math.abs(b.h - height)
            ? a
            : b
        )])
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```